# How to take out min and max price from a given data in batch file

Tags: batch-file, max

I am able to take out `max` price from a given data but when it comes to `min` value it is showing default 0.00000

```
@echo on

echo "file init

call ec2-describe-spot-price-history -H --instance-type t1.micro --start-time 2014-06-30T10:00:00 --end-time 2014-06-30T13:00:00 >> out.txt

echo "file written"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%i in (out.txt) do echo %%i

SET "min=0.000000"
SET "max=9.999999"

FOR /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a IN (out.txt) DO (
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%i IN ("%%a") DO (

IF %%i gtr !max! (SET "max=%%i"&SET "maxline=%%a")
IF %%i lss !min! (SET "min=%%i"&SET "minline=%%a")
)
)

ECHO max is %max% IN %maxline%
ECHO min is %min% IN %minline%

echo "file written"

echo "file done"
pause
```

**Output of a batch file**

```
C:\Users\nikunj\Desktop>echo "file init
"file init

C:\Users\nikunj\Desktop>call ec2-describe-spot-price-history -H --instance-type t1.micro --start-time 2014-06-30T10:00:0
"file written"
Type    Price   Timestamp       InstanceType    ProductDescription      AvailabilityZone
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.006100        2014-06-30T10:51:39+0530        t1.micro        Windows us-east-1d
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.006100        2014-06-30T10:51:39+0530        t1.micro        Windows us-east-1a
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.006100        2014-06-30T10:51:38+0530        t1.micro        Windows us-east-1b
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.006100        2014-06-30T05:07:12+0530        t1.micro        SUSE Linux  us-east-1d
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.006100        2014-06-30T02:43:23+0530        t1.micro        SUSE Linux  us-east-1a
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.006100        2014-06-29T22:45:09+0530        t1.micro        SUSE Linux  us-east-1b
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.003100        2014-06-29T22:45:08+0530        t1.micro        Linux/UNIX  us-east-1b
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.003100        2014-06-29T21:12:03+0530        t1.micro        Linux/UNIX  us-east-1d
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.003100        2014-06-29T21:12:03+0530        t1.micro        Linux/UNIX  us-east-1a
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.006100        2014-06-29T10:48:03+0530        t1.micro        Windows us-east-1d
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.006100        2014-06-29T10:48:03+0530        t1.micro        Windows us-east-1a
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE       0.006100        2014-06-29T10:48:03+0530        t1.micro        Windows us-east-1b

max is 0.006100 IN SPOTINSTANCEPRICE    0.006100        2014-06-29T10:48:03+0530        t1.micro    Windows     us-east-

min is 0.000000 IN

"file written"
"file done"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I would like to know how to retrieve the `min` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, when you define the initial values for `min` and `max`, you should change the values to

```
SET "min=99999999"
SET "max=........"
```

That way, any value will be initially less than the value in the `min` variable and larger than the value in the `max` variable.

Comment: i can share the out put...                                             max is 0.006100 IN SPOTINSTANCEPRICE
min is 99999999 IN
"file written"
"file done"
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @user323041, i think you are missing a `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` before `echo file init`

Comment: thanks i got the min price but can u help in 1 more thing , if i want both max n min price what i ve to do

Comment: @user323041 with the corrections indicated, your posted code should get both max and min. Where is the problem?

Comment: thanks , there is no such problem but according to the post i can take out the min value from the batch file , but now i want to take out max also with min , so can u help me or shold i change the post name .

Comment: no sir it is not giving max , it is giving me only min                        out put of batch file                                                max is Price IN Type    Price   Timestamp       InstanceType    ProductDescription      AvailabilityZone
min is 0.003100 IN SPOTINSTANCEPRICE    0.003100        2014-06-29T22:45:08+0530        t1.micro    Linux/UNIX  us-east-1b
"file done"
Press any key to continue . . .f batch file :

Comment: @user323041, sorry, but in your posted code you have a `skip=1` to avoid inclusion of the header in the process of data. Did you changed it?

Comment: i dont want to but if u can help me like this that will be great , i ve also shared the output....

Comment: @user323041, i don`t want you to change it. My point is: if you have the `skip` clause in the `for` command, the line of titles should not be processed, so, you should not get the `Price` text in the `max` variable. Maybe, there is an aditional line before the header. Check your input file and adapt the `skip` clause to make the `for` command jump over the headers and go directly to the data records.